# Help with the facebook comments box

Tags: facebook

The comment box on my website is different to the one shown here - http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472/

My button says Post, theirs says comment and I don't get the option to reply or like a comment that someone has posted:/ The only options I have are message, delete & block the user. I also am having trouble using the login box in IE, but it works fine in firefox.

There is no help on the facebook developers forum and I am tearing my hair out with this:( You can see the comments box working here: http://www.roomfor5.co.uk/item/532

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out. The href attribute was missing in the comments code. Putting it in enabled the missing functionality.